# Refining an if/else in jquery?

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have the following code, whereby if a certain div has a specific class execute one block of isotope code with a default layout, or another class, execute the 2nd block with a masonry layout.

It works great, but would just like to refine the code a little. What would be the best way?

```
var $body = $('.c3');
if ($body.hasClass('.standard')) {
    var $container = $('.portfolio-items').imagesLoaded(function () {
        // Initialize isotope 
        $container.isotope({
            filter: '*',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear'
            }
        });
    });
} else {
    var $container = $('.portfolio-items').imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.isotope({
            filter: '*',
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear'
            },
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: 1
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Was hoping to refine a little more than that if possible?

Comment: Instead of calling this twice - var $container = $('.portfolio-items').imagesLoaded(function ()

etc...

that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing the code duplication by using an options object (which is really what isotope expects). This can look like the following:

```
// Default options
var isotopeOptions = {
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear'
    }
};
// Set specific options
var $body = $('.c3');
if ($body.hasClass('.standard')) {
    isotopeOptions.layoutMode = 'fitRows';
} else {
    isotopeOptions.layoutMode = 'masonry';
    isotopeOptions.masonry = {
        columnWidth: 1
    };
}
var $container = $('.portfolio-items').imagesLoaded(function() {
    $container.isotope(isotopeOptions);
});
```

If one case is more likely than the other, you could think about setting e.g. `'fitRows'` as the default layout and thus remove one of the if branches.